# XSSER get and post

Tags: penetration-test, xss, kali-linux

I am using xsser for XSS vulnerability testing and I have a doubt about the parameters when it's a POST method.
I have tried against DVWA (which uses get) with success like this:

```
xsser -u "http://server.com/vulnerabilities/" -g "xss_r/?name=" --cookie="PHPSESSID=vjs31bec4gfvob6bcjmau2a644; security=low" -s
```

Now, against a web that uses post in the url and a form I have tried this without success, it seem malformer url, this is the url: http://server.com/post.php?id=1

```
xsser -u "http://server.com/post.php?id=1" -p "title=1234&author=12r&text=++++++++12r&submit=Enviar+consulta" -s

xsser -u "http://server.com/post.php?id=1" -p "?title=1234&author=12r&text=++++++++12r&submit=Enviar+consulta" -s

xsser -u "http://server.com/" -p "post.php?title=1234&author=12r&text=++++++++12r&submit=Enviar+consulta" -s
```

None of this have working, any idea¿?
By the way, I got the values of the post with Live HTTP Headers in firefox.
Thank you in advance